# mysql insert on different dbs

Tags: sql, mysql

I have different databases and when I try inseret I get error 1064

here is my statement

```
Insert into (`database1.table1`.`column`) Value ('1');
```

what am I doing wrong

thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to use correct syntax

```
INSERT INTO database1.table1 (column) VALUES('1')
```

Answer (score 2):

In mysql it would be something like

```
INSERT INTO `database1`.`table1` (`column`) VALUE ('1')
```